# Maven: release checkout with version number in path

Tags: java, maven, release

I have simple Maven project with release plugin. I use standart procedure like 
mvn release:prepare release:perform -Pprofile.
here is my definition for maven release plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <arguments>-f pom.xml</arguments>
     <baseDirectory>${basedir}</baseDirectory>
     <workingDirectory>${basedir}/releases/</workingDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After each release I've got new release version in /release/ folder.
But I wont to store history of checkouted project in following structure:
release/1.1/
release/1.2/
release/1.3/

etc - eg make checkout on release:perform in own directory with release version number. Is it simple way to do it and substitute release version (or tag name) as checkout path ?

Comment: Why are you not using the default location (target) folder instead...?

Comment: target folder will be overwritten on every release - so I cant handle release checkouts history in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the checkout done by `release:perform`, the variable `${project.version}` only holds the project snapshot version.

One way to do it would be to [add a goal](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals) to be executed when `release:perform` is called. This could be an ant task that copies the content of the default checkout folder to where you want it to be

You could configure `maven-release-plugin` this way (this is untested code) :

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <arguments>-f pom.xml</arguments>
     <baseDirectory>${basedir}</baseDirectory>
     <goals>antrun:run deploy</goals>
     <!-- use default workingDirectory -->
   </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <copy todir="${basedir}/releases/${project.version}">
                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/checkout"/>
             </copy>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, in this case (and in this place) this variable are initialized when plugin initialization started and contains x.x.x-SNAPSHOT version, not a release. I've tested this case without success